# Why do I keep getting the error: cannot find symbol for variables "weight" and "planet"?

Tags: java, variables, compiler-errors

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter weight: ");
weight = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Which planet: ");
planet = input.nextInt();

int venus = 1;
int mars = 2;
int jupiter = 3;
int saturn = 4;
int uranus = 5;
int neptune = 6;

if (planet == 1)
{
  venus_weight = weight * 0.78;
  System.out.println(+ venus_weight);
}
else if (planet == 2)
{
  mars_weight = weight * 0.39;
  System.out.println(+ mars_weight);
}
else if (planet == 3)
{
  jupiter_weight = weight * 2.56;
  System.out.println(+ jupiter_weight);
}
else if (planet == 4)
{
  saturn_weight = weight * 1.17;
  System.out.println(+ saturn_weight);
}
else if (planet == 5)
{
  uranus_weight = weight * 1.05;
  System.out.println(+ uranus_weight);
}
else
{
  neptune_weight = weight * 1.23;
  System.out.println(+ neptune_weight);
}
```

The variables `weight` and `planet` are not being recognized for some reason and basically every other variable in this code. I thought it was originally a scanner issue but `input.nextInt();` is being used in both cases, and `input` was declared as a `Scanner`.

Comment: Because you don't have any variables called `weight` or `planet`?

Comment: You are declaring `venus` but not `venus_weight`, etc. Also, you can change all those if-else statements into a `switch` statement, if so desired

Answer (score 2):

At least in the code you posted they are not declared.

Change to :

```
System.out.println("Enter weight: ");
int weight = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Which planet: ");
int planet = input.nextInt();
```